# The result wasn't what I expected what i expect

Tags: c++

The problem is to delete all  the biggest number 
for example: 
cin:  1 2 3 4 5
cout: 1 2 3 4

cin:  5 1 2 3 5
cout: 1 2 3

cin:  5 5 1 2 5
cout: 1 2

cin:  5 5 5 1 5 
cout: 1

and here is where things go wrong: 
whenever my biggest number locate in the first and the last location with other location, the code print out the wrong result 
please look at these example for better understanding: 
cin:  5 5 1 2 5
expected cout: 1 2 
but instead it cout: 5 1

cin:  5 5 1 5 5
expected cout: 1
but instead it cout: 5

I think the problem occured in the delete function but I can't  figure out what went wrong no matter how many time i rechecked, i would be very happy if someone can help me solve this problem.
and sorry for my sloppy writing and bad english 
here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void Insert(int a[] ,int n)
{
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout << "a[" << i << "]= ";
        cin >> a[i];
    }
}
void Delete(int a[], int n, int Biggestt)
{
    int BiggestLocation;
    for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
    {
        if (a[i]==Biggestt)
        {
            BiggestLocation=i;
        }
    }
    for (int i=BiggestLocation; i<n-1; i++)
    {
        a[i]=a[i+1];
    }
}
int Biggest(int a[],int n)
{
    int Biggesttt=a[0];
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (Biggesttt<a[i])
        {
            Biggesttt=a[i];
        }
    }
    return Biggesttt;
}
void PrintOut(int a[],int n)
{
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
}
int main()
{
    int n,OriginalCount;
    int Count=0;
    cout << "Insert n: ";
    cin >>n;
    int a[100];
    Insert(a,n);
    int Biggestttt=Biggest(a,n);
    for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==Biggestttt)
        {
            Count++;
        }
    }
    OriginalCount=Count;
    while(Count!=0)
    {
        {
            Delete(a,n,Biggestttt);
        }
        Count--;
    }
    if (a[n-1]==Biggestttt && OriginalCount==0)
    {
        PrintOut(a,n-1);
    }
    else if (a[n-1]!=Biggestttt && OriginalCount!=0)
    {
        PrintOut(a,n-OriginalCount);
    }
    else if (a[n-1]==Biggestttt && OriginalCount!=0)
    {
        PrintOut(a,n-OriginalCount-1);
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you required to you C-arrays (e.g. `int a[100];`) or you can use C++ vectors (e.g. `vect <int> a;`)? (it makes things easier)

Comment: What is the head line telling me? Please can you correct it ;) I have no idea what it should tell me.

Answer (score 1):

You are not far off. You biggest issues have to do with using `void function ()` for all your functions. By using `void` as the type, you lose the ability to `return` valid (and needed) information.

For example in `void Delete(int a[], int n, int Biggestt)` the number of elements that remain in `a[]` will change as each element matching the `Biggestt` are removed from the array -- but you have no way of returning the final number of elements in the array after the removals take place. You can either change your return type from `void` to `int` and return an updated `n`, or you can pass `n` as a pointer parameter so when it is update within the function, its updated value is available back in the calling function when `Delete()` returns.

Additionally, your logic in `main()` is quite jumbled. You already have functions created to handle your needs, so `main()` should be relatively clean and have no more than a couple of variables to deal with. You could do something like:

```
int main (void)
{
    int n, b,
        a[MAXINT];

    cout << "Insert n: ";
    if (!(cin >> n)) {      /* validate ALL user input */
        cerr << "(invalid conversion or user canceled)\n";
        return 1;
    }

    Insert (a, n);          /* insert all array values */
    cout << "original: ";   /* output the original */
    PrintOut (a, n);

    b = Biggest (a, n);     /* find the biggest number in the arry */
    Delete (a, &n, b);      /* delete all occurrences in array */

    cout << "big deleted: ";    /* output array with biggest removed */
    PrintOut (a, n);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** since your `Delete()` function has been left `void` a pointer to `n` was passed as a parameter so the final value of `n` after element deletion will be available back in the calling function (`main()` here))

Putting it altogether and making adjustments to the logic in `Delete()`, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define MAXINT 100

void Insert (int a[], int n)
{
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout << "a[" << i << "]= ";
        cin >> a[i];
    }
}

void Delete(int *a, int *n, int Biggestt)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < *n;)
    {
        if (*n > 1 && a[i] == Biggestt)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < *n; j++)
                a[j-1] = a[j];
            (*n)--;     /* if biggest removed, decrement n */
        }
        else
            i++;        /* only advance if biggest not removed at index */
    }
}

int Biggest(int a[],int n)
{
    int Biggesttt=a[0];
    for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (Biggesttt<a[i])
        {
            Biggesttt=a[i];
        }
    }
    return Biggesttt;
}

void PrintOut(int a[],int n)
{
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout << " " << a[i];
    }
    cout << '\n';
}

int main (void)
{
    int n, b,
        a[MAXINT];

    cout << "Insert n: ";
    if (!(cin >> n)) {      /* validate ALL user input */
        cerr << "(invalid conversion or user canceled)\n";
        return 1;
    }

    Insert (a, n);          /* insert all array values */
    cout << "original: ";   /* output the original */
    PrintOut (a, n);

    b = Biggest (a, n);     /* find the biggest number in the arry */
    Delete (a, &n, b);      /* delete all occurrences in array */

    cout << "big deleted: ";    /* output array with biggest removed */
    PrintOut (a, n);

    return 0;
}
```

**Exmple Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/remove_biggest
Insert n: 5
a[0]= 5
a[1]= 1
a[2]= 2
a[3]= 3
a[4]= 5
original:  5 1 2 3 5
*n: 3
*n: 3
*n: 3
big deleted:  1 2 3

$ ./bin/remove_biggest
Insert n: 4
a[0]= 5
a[1]= 5
a[2]= 1
a[3]= 5
original:  5 5 1 5
*n: 1
big deleted:  1
```

What if all number in `a[...]` are the same? You have to be able to handle that case. The logic in `Delete()` now retains 1 number if the are all the same number. You may also choose to leave them ALL as there is no `Biggestt`. The are simultaneously the largest and smallest at the same time. How you handle it is up to you.

```
$ ./bin/remove_biggest
Insert n: 4
a[0]= 5
a[1]= 5
a[2]= 5
a[3]= 5
original:  5 5 5 5
*n: 1
big deleted:  5
```

If they were all the same Big number we just deleted all of them leaving 1 as it is also the minimum.

**Using a Reference `int& n` Instead of a Pointer**

In response to your comment and the suggestion by Fei Xiang, C++ allows you to pass a reference to `n` in `Delete()` instead of a pointer to ensure changes to `n` are visible back in the calling function (`main` here). The crux of the matter is when you simply pass a parameter to a function, the function receives a copy and any changes made to the variable within the function are lost on return. C++ provides a reference (e.g. `int& n`) which essentially passes an alias to the original and any changes made to the reference are changes made to the original. This is a refinement over passing the **address of** the variable because it does avoid having to dereference the pointer.

Using a reference, `Delete()` could be re-written as follows:

```
void Delete (int *a, int& n, int Biggestt)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n;)
    {
        if (n > 1 && a[i] == Biggestt)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
                a[j-1] = a[j];
            n--;        /* if biggest removed, decrement n */
        }
        else
            i++;        /* only advance if biggest not removed at index */
    }
}
```

The call to `Delete()` in `main()` would be:

```
Delete (a, n, b);       /* delete all occurrences in array */
```

And you have gotten rid of the so-called `'*'` marks `:)`  (that Fei)

Comment: hey david, thanks for your answer, but can you  somehow do it without the * mark,
thanks again for your time

Comment: Why not use references? This is C++.

Comment: Should have, will tweak it.

Comment: @ThaiHuynh - you have to pass `n` as a pointer to `Delete()` since you do not return any value from a `void` function. This allows the value of `n` to be updated in `Delete()` and the change be visible back in the calling function (`main` here). The alternative is to change the return type for `Delete`, e.g. `int Delete (int *a, int n, int Biggestt)` and then in `main` assign the return, e.g. `n = Delete (a, n, b);` That would be fine as well and you could get rid of the *dereferences* (e.g. the `'*'` before `'n'` in `Delete`).

Comment: The alternative is to pass `n` as a reference -- which also allows you to avoid the derefernce (which was a C way of doing it). I'll drop an update.

Comment: @FeiXiang updated -- thanks you. Avoids having to learn about those darn `'*'` marks `:)`

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void Insert(int a[] ,int n)
{
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout << "a[" << i << "]= ";
        cin >> a[i];
    }
}
void Delete(int a[], int n, int Biggestt)
{
    int BiggestLocation;
    for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
    {
        if (a[i]==Biggestt)
        {
            a[i]=-1;
        }
    }
    for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(a[i-1]==-1)
        a[i-1]=a[i];
    }
}
int Biggest(int a[],int n)
{
    int Biggesttt=a[0];
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (Biggesttt<a[i])
        {
            Biggesttt=a[i];
        }
    }
    return Biggesttt;
}
void PrintOut(int a[],int n)
{
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
}
int main()
{
    int n,OriginalCount;
    int Count=0;
    cout << "Insert n: ";
    cin >>n;
    int a[100];
    Insert(a,n);
    int Biggestttt=Biggest(a,n);
    for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==Biggestttt)
        {
            Count++;
        }
    }
    OriginalCount=Count;
    while(Count!=0)
    {
        {
            Delete(a,n,Biggestttt);
        }
        Count--;
    }
    if (a[n-1]==Biggestttt && OriginalCount==0)
    {
        PrintOut(a,n-1);
    }
    else if (a[n-1]!=Biggestttt && OriginalCount!=0)
    {
        PrintOut(a,n-OriginalCount);
    }
    else if (a[n-1]==Biggestttt && OriginalCount!=0)
    {
        PrintOut(a,n-OriginalCount-1);
    }

return 0;
}
```

TRY THIS CODE.
Just equate all the instances of biggest number to -1 and later overwrite them with the neighboring elements which are not equal to -1.

Comment: Just equate all the instances of biggest number to -1 and later overwrite them with the neighboring elements which are not equal to -1.

Comment: Posting blocks of code without explanation is not useful.

Comment: While this code might work, it's better to tell OP what changes were made.

Comment: k thanks for your suggestions. I forgot to add explanation. that's why i commented the explanation below my answer. Don't give down votes without seeing the whole conversation.

Comment: @ChallaSaiBhanuTeja You must rather edit your answer to post the explanation.